# How to check if the data values passed through the foreach loop are the same or different by PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Controller is as below.

```
$workings = DB::table('workings')
                     ->where('user_name', $user_name)
                     ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
                     ->orwhere(function ($query) use($user_name) {
                         $query->where('user_name', $user_name)
                         ->whereMonth('deleted_at', date('m'));
                     })
                     ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                     ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'asc')
                     ->paginate(22);
```

If Laravel View code is as below.

```
...
@foreach($workings as $working)
  <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>user_name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>$user->user_name
      <td>$working->id</td>
      <td>$working->user_name</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach

@if("all user_name is same")
 user xxxx's total duration is xxxxxx.
@else
 ...
@endif
...
```

so if result is as below, then how to check user_name is same or different?

```
ID   user_name
1    john
1    john
2    michael
   ...
   ...
```

then how to check these user_name is all same or different by if-statement?

in Laravel 5.6ver.

**I solved by myself.**

**in Controller**

```
 $userNameDiff = count($query->pluck('user_name')->unique());

 return view('workings.index', compact('userNameDiff'));
```

**in View**

```
@if($userNameDiff > 1)
...
@else
...
@endif
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be better to alter the query when fetching the users, grouping them by user ID's and adding a 'SUM(1) as total_duration'.

Comment: don't do it in the view!

Comment: It wasn't clear to me what exactly you're looking for but there is `count()` and `sum()` you can use for gathering data of each user. As your question not clear i just provide sample for you `user::select('duration')->where('user_name', $user->user_name)->count();` something like that, obviously this is not your answer but gives you the idea.

Comment: @OleHaugset, When a program user searches for a user_name through the search input box, then result will show all similar names into this View file. My goal is to implement a View file that looks different depending on the result.

Comment: You can store all usernames in an array while iteration, then  use array_unique () to remove duplicate items and check if length is "1" then all users are unique.

Comment: how your query returns duplicates like 
1    John
1    John
in the first place ?

Comment: @MohammadIstanboli, see my revised one.

Comment: @SonamMohite, I solved with your hint, thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself.

**in Controller**

```
 $userNameDiff = count($query->pluck('user_name')->unique());

 return view('workings.index', compact('userNameDiff'));
```

**in View**

```
@if($userNameDiff > 1)
...
@else
...
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @OleHaugset and @Gogol don't do this in views. Views is used only for presentation for data. Better way to get this result by db query and represent in views.